# How to extract a OLE table from a excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, ole

I'm having some trouble, trying to extract an OLE table form an Excel file. I can open it but I want to save it.
I am using.

excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = True

```
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/user/doc/test.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets("Folha2")

O = ws.OLEObjects(2)
O.Verb()
O.save() // dont work
```