# How to extract OLE objects from Excel table using Python?

Tags: python, excel, ole, cheminformatics

I would like to use Python to extract OLE-objects from an Excel table into the Windows clipboard.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39457262/7295599) didn't help further since it is for VBA.
And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55685381/7295599) is still unanswered.

Assuming the given Excel table (with ChemDraw or ChemSketch OLE objects):

[image]

There are some Python modules which can handle Excel files, e.g. `openpyxl`, `xlrd`.
The module `win32clipboard` can put data into the clipboard.

My Problems:

1. I don't see how to get the embedded OLE object to the clipboard. Probably, `openpyxl` and `xlrd` together with `win32clipboard` are not suited for this?
2. There is a Python module `oletools` which maybe can do it but I don't understand how it works.
   https://pypi.org/project/oletools/

From  this page:

> `oleobj`: to extract embedded objects from OLE files.

This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, however, I couldn't find any MCVEs. And unfortunately, the documentation of `oleobj` is basically reduced to: "read the source code and find out yourself". I would be grateful for hints and assistance.

My code so far:

```
### trying to extract OLE objects from Excel table into clipboard
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import win32clipboard as clpbd

def set_clipboard(data):
    clpbd.OpenClipboard()
    clpbd.EmptyClipboard()
    clpbd.SetClipboardText(data)    # I'm aware, this is only for text, is there anything for OLEs?
    clpbd.CloseClipboard()

def print_clipboard():
    clpbd.OpenClipboard()
    data = clpbd.GetClipboardData()
    clpbd.CloseClipboard()
    print(data)

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'tbChemOLE.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

myName = ws['A3'].value    # result: napthalene
myImage = ws['B3'].value   # result: None
myObject = ws['C3'].value  # result: None

set_clipboard(myName)
print_clipboard()          # result: Naphtalene
# set_clipboard(myImage)   # crash, because myImage is None
print_clipboard()     
# set_clipboard(myObject)  # crash, because myObject is None
print_clipboard()        

wb.close()
### end of code
```

Comment: Ha, I can't comment anything of value but how funny that people who want to do this are so often chemists :) I googled this with a vision to extracting ChemDraw objects too; didn't expect to find the first example a ChemDraw one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43154439/7295599), where the OP actually didn't want the OLE objects on the clipboard, but for me it is fine. Actually, no need for `openpyxl` or `xlrd`, but `win32com.client` is required.

I can get all OLE objects, however, they are indexed (probably) in the sequence of their addition.
So I need to create a dictionary with the row index as key and a set of OLE object index of and name as value.

**Code:**

```
### copy OLE object in certain cell to clipboard
import win32com.client as win32
import win32clipboard

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
ffname = r'C:\Test\tbChemOLE.xlsx'
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(ffname)
ws = wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
objs = ws.OLEObjects()

def get_all_OLEs():
    oleNo_dict = {}     # dictionary for all OLE objects
    for i in range(1,len(objs)+1):    # loop all OLE objects
        obj = objs.Item(i) 
        myRow = obj.TopLeftCell.Row        # row of OLE object
        myName = ws.Cells(myRow,1).Value   # corresponding name
        oleNo_dict[myRow] = (i, myName)
    return oleNo_dict

def get_OLE(row):
    try: 
        objs[oleNo_dict[row][0]].Copy()
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(0xC004) # Binary access
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    return oleNo_dict[row]
    # and OLE is on clipboard if found

oleNo_dict = get_all_OLEs()

row = 4
myMolecule = get_OLE(row)
print(myMolecule[1], "OLE object is now on the clipboard.")

wb.Close()
excel.Application.Quit()
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
Anthracene OLE object is now on the clipboard.
```

Answer (score 1):

I built a python module to do exactly this check it out over here. https://pypi.org/project/AttachmentsExtractor/ also the module can be run on any os.

after installing the library use the following code snippet:

```
 from AttachmentsExtractor import extractor
            
 abs_path_to_file='Please provide absolute path here '
 path_to_destination_directory = 'Please provide path of the directory where the extracted attachments should be stored'
 extractor.extract(abs_path_to_file,path_to_destination_directory) # returns true if one or more attachments are found else returns false.
```